# Can't create a SSH session by Keys Auth with openssh, becoming crazy

Tags: ssh-keys, openssh

Here is what I did:

**client:** => generated 2 keys with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

=> sent **id_rsa.pub** to server (with scp) and put it to **~/.ssh/authorized_keys**

**Server:** in /etc/ssh/shd_config:

=> uncommented AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

=> PasswordAuthentication no

=> UsePAM no

And I restarted the server: service sshd restart

**Problem:** when I try to connect "`ssh user@IP_Server -v`" and after I've put my passphrase.

I get the following logs:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:HMjzNl/zNrs...3m6SYDQ64ZoHeL6k
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Do you have any idea where this logs comes from ?

Cheers

Comment: `Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory` This is what you need to check. Check private key path

Comment: @Hrabosch There is no id_dsa indeed, but it's because I've put only id_rsa in /root/.ssh, and I just want to use rsa keys...

Comment: @Hrabosch I don't understand why openssh continue to look for other keys

Comment: Try to look at ssh/config and check `IdentityFile`, what is there?

Comment: It's all uncommented both sides

Comment: something strange is in sshd_config HostKey is set to /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key maybe I should change it to the path to id_rsa.pub ?

Comment: Apparently there are 2 places to put the public key on the server, either ~/.ssh/authorized_keys either /etc/ssh, which one should I use ?

Comment: `ssh_host_rsa_key — The RSA private key used by the sshd daemon for version 2 of the SSH protocol.` and `id_rsa.pub — The RSA public key*used by ssh for version 2 of the SSH protocol`, one is for public and next is for private! :)

Comment: Use `authorized_keys` to keep public keys.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-ssh-configfiles.html for more informations to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought that `authorized_keys` was a Directory, and put the public Key in it. But actually it's a file ! Solved !